# Did not get friend-list of facebook using Koala gem Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing `Rails 4 application` where i have to fetched all facebook friends of login user.

I logged in using FB successfully but when tried to fetch `friends list` using below code where i got blank.

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
profile = @graph.get_object("me")
@friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends", api_version: 'v2.0')
```

I read `FB API document` where we can get friends only which are using `same app`. My friends use that same app but still not fetch any friend.

What is issue or missing something?

Thanks

Comment: `@friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends", api_version: 'v2.0')` -This should return your friends who have authenticated this app using their FB account. In my case, it is working.

Comment: Can you send me that code and what settings done in Fb app.

Comment: I have not done any specific setting in either of my code or app settings. I just get the `access_token` from FB API omniauth callback and when try `Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token).get_connections("me", "friends", api_version: 'v2.0')` , I get my list of friends who have authenticated the FB app.

Comment: Ok, can i see your project link if available? How to get access_token from FB API? any specific method?